# Convert hash with integers to list with hashes

Tags: elixir

What's an optimal way to convert this hash:

```
%{
    "0" => [
        %{"foo" => 1, "baz" => 10}
    ], 
    "1" => [
        %{"foo" => 2, "baz" => 11}
    ]
}
```

to a list like this?

```
[
    %{"foo" => 1, "baz" => 10},
    %{"foo" => 2, "baz" => 11}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [`Map.values/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Map.html#values/2) would definitely work, the [`Kernel.SpecialForms/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension is probably a more flexible way to go since it allows you to filter and/or modify the result in-place.

```rb
input = %{
  "0" => [
    %{"foo" => 1, "baz" => 10}
  ], 
  "1" => [
    %{"foo" => 2, "baz" => 11}
  ]
}

for {_, [map]} <- input, do: map
#⇒ [%{"baz" => 10, "foo" => 1}, %{"baz" => 11, "foo" => 2}]
```

In case you expect to have *more* than one element in each list in values, use [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#reduce/3):

```rb
Enum.reduce(input, [], fn {_, maps}, acc -> acc ++ maps end)
#⇒ [%{"baz" => 10, "foo" => 1}, %{"baz" => 11, "foo" => 2}]
```

---

Another possibility would be to use [`Enum.flat_map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#flat_map/2):

```rb
Enum.flat_map(input, &elem(&1, 1))
#⇒ [%{"baz" => 10, "foo" => 1}, %{"baz" => 11, "foo" => 2}]
```

---

FWIW, the solution with `Map.values/1` (not recommended):

```rb
input
|> Map.values()
|> Enum.flat_map(& &1)
#⇒ [%{"baz" => 10, "foo" => 1}, %{"baz" => 11, "foo" => 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
original = %{
    "0" => [
        %{"foo" => 1, "baz" => 10}
    ], 
    "1" => [
        %{"foo" => 2, "baz" => 11}
    ]
}

values_from_original = original |> Map.values

result = for e <- values_from_original, do: e |> Enum.at(0)
```

Comment: Please follow Elixir style guidelines when answering. Pipes are to be used if and only the number of links in the chain is greater or equal to 2. Parentheses are mandatory even for void arguments.